# Detecting touches in HUDLayer and GameLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need touch detection in HUDLayer and GameLayer also.
Because when player.position > 480, user can't interact with GameLayer properly.
Touch location is relevant to HUDLayer, which is good but i need to have touches on both layers. I tried ccTouchesBegan methods with touching enabled, in both layers but Log is still showing same touch location twice. How can i do this?

GameLayer.mm

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   for(UITouch *touch in touches ) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
      location = [CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
      NSLog(@"Touch X: %f Y: %f", location.x, location.y);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand right what do you want to do, you just need to convert touch position to node space with

```
[layer convertToNodeSpace: glTouchLocation];
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i needed. Where google let me down, you prevailed :)